# UIAlertView has scrollable title and message on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView with text in it that can be displayed on iOS6 without any problem.
However in iOS7 the title and message of this alert are in a scrollview.

I'm creating the alert with following code

```
self.newCategoryAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTitleNewCategory", nil)
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTextNewCategory", nil)
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonCancel", nil)
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", nil), nil] autorelease];

self.newCategoryAlertView.tag = alertViewTypeNewCategory;
self.newCategoryAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
[[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault];
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;

[self.newCategoryAlertView show];
```

The result on iOS7 is this:[image: the result on iOS7]

I tried to make the the text shorter with no success and the documentation of UIAlertView didn't give me a hint.

How do I workaround this behavior?

EDIT:

This is how it looks when scrolled down. As you can see the complete message is visible.

[image: same alert scrolled down]

Comment: You can't. Feel free to raise a radar against it (but don't hold out for a change).

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion that's a good behaviour, as there's no space in the screen to show the keyboard and also de UIAlert. I'm almost sure that if you make the app work in portrait orientation, the alert will show ok with no scrollable title and message.

If the app only runs in landscape orientation, and you don't want to have a scrollable view, I guess the best solution will be maybe to keep the UIAlert message, but taking away the UIAlert tilte.

I hope this helped!

Comment: I wasn't clear enough sorry. It's indeed a good behavior if the space to show the alerts isn't available. I updated my post with a screenshot of the same alert scrolled down. As you can see the complete message is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a custom control [URBAlertView](https://github.com/u10int/URBAlertView). I found a similar problem with this & I have reported that to the author on the [github here](https://github.com/u10int/URBAlertView/issues/5).

There was a fix provided by the author under the commit [here](https://github.com/u10int/URBAlertView/commit/1ff4ff298606b0f258d3e48f02cb4afc3814fe0e). However you can also refer the top three commits on the repo [here](https://github.com/u10int/URBAlertView/commits/master).

I hope that may help you all to figure out a solution